# Imprimir array en php

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente array, como puedo imprimirlo de manera ordenado ?

```
Array ( [return] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [codigo_materia] => 3525 [desc_materia] => Aprender Biologia [id] => 1 [nombre_materia] => Biologia ) [1] => Array ( [codigo_materia] => 3678 [desc_materia] => Aprender Quimica [id] => 2 [nombre_materia] => Quimica ) ) )
```

me gustaría que se imprima de esta manera: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese array en si es una lista que me retorna una función en un webservice es una respuesta soap.

```js
require_once './nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost:8080/WebApplicationMaterias/NewWebServiceMaterias?WSDL', true);
$result = $client->call('getMateria');
```

cuando uso `echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";`
me imprime lo siguiente:

```js
Array
(
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [codigo_materia] => 3525
                    [desc_materia] => Aprender Biologia
                    [id] => 1
                    [nombre_materia] => Biologia
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [codigo_materia] => 3678
                    [desc_materia] => Aprender Quimica
                    [id] => 2
                    [nombre_materia] => Quimica
                )

        )

)
```

y con var_dump me imprime:

```js
array(1) {
  ["return"]=>
  &array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["codigo_materia"]=>
      &string(4) "3525"
      ["desc_materia"]=>
      &string(17) "Aprender Biologia"
      ["id"]=>
      &string(1) "1"
      ["nombre_materia"]=>
      &string(8) "Biologia"
    }
    [1]=>
    &array(4) {
      ["codigo_materia"]=>
      &string(4) "3678"
      ["desc_materia"]=>
      &string(16) "Aprender Quimica"
      ["id"]=>
      &string(1) "2"
      ["nombre_materia"]=>
      &string(7) "Quimica"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con imprimirlo y que sucede cuando ejecutas tu código??

Comment: osea me gustaría imprimirlo de  una manera organizada. como una especie de tabla. pero e intentado de varias formas y no me ejecuta.

Comment: organizada para quien y donde??

Comment: Cuando lo muestras en tu página no sale separado en líneas??

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($tuArr);echo "</pre>";

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas mira la imagen amigo así quiero que me imprima.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta la edite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
foreach($result['return'] as $elemento){
     foreach($elemento as $key => $data){
        echo $key.": ".$data."<br />";
     }
     echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.. por tu tiempo. útil respuesta .

Comment: Si te funciono porfavor marcala como aceptada. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso en específico, podrías programar algo similar a lo que ha dicho Alfredo, pero teniendo en cuenta que el Array que tienes es tridimensional y que hay que ordenar los campos.

Así pues, yo haría algo así:

```php
// Obtenemos la respuesta con las materias
require_once './nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost:8080/WebApplicationMaterias/NewWebServiceMaterias?WSDL', true);
$result = $client->call('getMateria');

// Ahora iteramos sobre cada materia:
foreach ($result["return"] as $materia) {
  ksort($materia); // Ordenamos las propiedades de esta materia
  // Iteramos sobre estas propiedades, ahora ya ordenadas
  foreach ($materia as $campo => $valor) {
    // Imprimimos la propiedad de la materia correspondiente a
    // cada iteración (por ejemplo, "codigo_materia: 3542")
    echo $campo.": ".$valor."<br>";
  }
  echo "<br>"; // Saltamos de línea para separar las diferentes materias
}
```

Yo aquí lo he hecho un poco "cutre" separando los campos por un salto de línea, y además estoy suponiendo que estás usando PHP para cargar dinámicamente páginas HTML y no como CLI (en este caso en vez de acabar cada línea con `<br>` terminaríamos con `\n` o `PHP_EOL`), pero en todo caso posteriormente ya puedes retocar este código para definir la estructura que más te guste y luego añadirle estilos mediante CSS, si así lo deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder recorrer un array asociativo, como el que estas mostrando se puede hacer con un foreach:

Si el arreglo es de una dimensión puede ser asi:

```
<?php
$valores = array("valor_uno" => "Alfredo", "valor_dos" => "Jorge", "valor_tres" => "Diana");

foreach($valores as $key => $value){
    echo $value.PHP_EOL;
}
//LO CUAL IMPRIMIRÁ
//Alfredo
//Jorge
//Diana
```

> Al echo que esta por dentro ya le puedes concatenar la estructura de
>   las etiquetas de una tabla normal como lo son tr y td y al ser un
>   bucle te imprimirá tantas filas de tabla como valores tenga tu arreglo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, veras lo que pasa esque estoy recibiendo la respuesta de un SOAP en una lista. por cuanto cuando uso tu solucion me imprime solamente esto.                              
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_client\index.php on line 19
Array